# Need help in getting data from firebase into a string[] array. Tried all available methods but stuck with getting only the last value

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am trying to get all the values stored in a firebase into two separate string[] array. I am getting values but while displaying it into listview, it only shows the last added value. I am using a custom adapter class as well.

```
Database.child("users").child(mUserId).child("locs").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

            final String[] main = {(String) ds.child("title").getValue()};
            final String[] sub = {(String) ds.child("addr").getValue()};
            System.out.println(main);//here i am getting 5 outputs like  [Ljava.lang.String;@88b5c49. i have 5 values in firebase too

            CustomAdapter adapter2 = new CustomAdapter(Location.this, main, sub);
            list.setAdapter(adapter2);
        }
    }
});
```

Custom Adapter class

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    private final Activity context;
    private final String[] main;
    private final String[] sub;
    public CustomAdapter(Activity context,
                         String[] main, String[] sub) {
        super(context, R.layout.layout, main);
        this.context = context;
        this.main = main;
        this.sub = sub;

    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout, null, true);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView txtSub=rowView.findViewById(R.id.subtitle);
        txtTitle.setText(main[position]);
        txtSub.setText(sub[position]);
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Comment: how many values do you get from `dataSnapshot.getChildren()`?

Comment: I am getting all the values but saving it into string gives only the last added value. For example if i use something like ` String title = ds.child("title").getValue(String.class);` inside the for loop and add it to listview I am getting what i want but the problem is i cant do further operations on the listview because clicking on it gives me the entire listview content while i only have to work with the title part.

Answer (score 0):

Try to move `String[] main`, `String[] sub` outside of the loop. then try to add all the values to these arrays inside the loop. Then after completing the loop call these

```
CustomAdapter adapter2 = new CustomAdapter(Location.this, main, sub);
list.setAdapter(adapter2);
```

The whole code should be something like this.

```
final String[] main; // declare it with the size it needs.
final String[] sub;  // declare it with the size it needs.              
for(DataSnapshot ds:dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
   // sum your result to main and sub
}
CustomAdapter adapter2 = new CustomAdapter(Location.this, main, sub);
list.setAdapter(adapter2);
```

Comment: how to declare size to main. I am new to this whole thing.